# Dynamic reconfigure GUI improvements

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm currently working on a [camera driver](https://github.com/srv/avt_vimba_camera) and I was wondering if any of the ideas I list here are even possible:

- Group some dynamic_reconfigure parameters into groups or "boxes" so that the end user can see that those parameters are related. Ex: Acquisition params, Trigger params, White balance params...
- Add tooltips or a info box whose content changes when the mouse hovers a particular parameter in the dynamic reconfigure gui.

And I've seen in the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile) that it's possible to have more than one config file in one ROS package. If the package contains more than one node, then the relationship is easy: one cfg file for each, but could it be possible to have more than one cfg file in the same node? Therefore, could I "group" the parameters I want in different cfg files and show them as a tree in the dynamic reconfigure gui?

I tried groups (even with [prosilica_camera](https://github.com/ros-drivers/prosilica_driver/commit/c232a54e47cfca358bc74b85bcaaa27617926842) example) in dynamic_reconfigure but whenever I open the GUI to see the params, reconfigure_gui crashes:

```
$ rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1394202876.542782] reconf loading #1/4 0.0 / 0.0sec node=/camera/image_raw/compressed
[INFO] [WallTime: 1394202876.546365] reconf loading #2/4 0.0 / 0.0sec node=/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
[INFO] [WallTime: 1394202876.547479] reconf loading #3/4 0.0 / 0.0sec node=/camera/image_raw/theora
[INFO] [WallTime: 1394202876.551956] reconf loading #4/4 0.0 / 0.01sec node=/prosilica_driver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/node_selector_widget.py", line 248, in _selection_changed_slot
    self._selection_selected(index_current, rosnode_name_selected)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/node_selector_widget.py", line 198, in _selection_selected
    item_widget = item_child.get_dynreconf_widget()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/treenode_qstditem.py", line 148, in get_dynreconf_widget
    self._param_name_raw)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/dynreconf_client_widget.py", line 57, in __init__
    group_desc, node_name)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/param_groups.py", line 152, in __init__
    self._create_node_widgets(config)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/param_groups.py", line 198, in _create_node_widgets
    widget = eval(_GROUP_TYPES[group['type']])(self.updater, group)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_reconfigure/param_groups.py", line 247, in __init__
    super(BoxGroup, self).__init__(updater, config)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136856/dynamic-reconfigure-gui-improvements/) by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1471 on 2014-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-07**:
the tooltip / info box idea seems useful enough. Maybe you could open an issue on github for future reference.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-03-10**:
Done. https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rqt_reconfigure GUI currently does not work very well with groups and there is an open ticket about it: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/162

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-03-10**:
Thanks Dirk, that's clearly the reason. I'll close the question.